# Как получить переменную после innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

Есть форма на странице, которая обновляется после ajax dataType:html,
с помощью element.innerHTML = res;

в res есть

```
<script>
   var cd = {"dates":{"min":"2020,4,18","max":"2020,4,25"}};
</script>
```

Возможно ли получить доступ к этой переменной?
console.log(cd);  - ничего не дает
console.log(window);  - ее нет

Или как передать объект?

Спасибо!

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш скрипт, вставленный через `element.innerHTML = res`, вообще работает? Попробуйте добавить туда `console.log` после объявления cd.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вставляю console.log(window) перед element.innerHTML = res и вставляю console.log(window)  после var cd, и вижу что это абсолютно разные объекты. соответственно в первом случае cd не видно, а во втором она уже есть...  Может есть варианты еще как то передать объект? Например вижу что яндекс пихает объекты в атрибут контейнера. Тогда вопрос встает - какие ограничения на длину объекта (кол-во символов), т.к. есть очень длинные объекты.

Comment: Вы опишите ваш задачу, что вы хотите сделать и для чего. Скорее всего есть  более удобные способы.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Форма заказа, набор полей (инпуты селекты и тд) постоянно меняется и рассчитывается на стороне сервера в зависимости от выбранных опций, меняется с помощью ajax innerhtml. Получается что после каждого обновления полей приходят новые данные, которые надо поймать и как то обработать. Вот и вопрос как этот объект с данными отправить, чтобы потом js обработать? Изменить dataType на json не могу(

Comment: А сервер можете менять? Отправляйте еще один запрос на данные. А лучше всего поменять ответ на json, в котором будет и разметка и данные.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Да я понимаю что json решил бы мою проблему, но там только html. Опыта у меня очень мало, скажите, а то что яндекс объекты вставляет в атрибуты тегов насколько это правильно? Таким методом без проблем можно отдать и получить на js все что хочешь., уже проверил работает.

Comment: Не томите уже, почему не можете использовать json? И, поскольку у нас диалог, я надеюсь, отвечайте на заданные вам вопросы :) В атрибуты вставлять можно, но надо экранировать некоторые специальные символы, например кавычки, переносы строк, обратный слеш, еще что-то.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko речь идёт о странице оформления заказа. Для того чтобы перейти на json, если знакомы с битриксом, потребуется с 0 разработать шаблон компонента с сохранением самого компонента, тк он находится на поддержке (обновляется). К этому не готов, займёт много времени и потребует много знаний, которых к сожалению нет.  В итоге пока сделал через атрибут, записывают туда объект, дальше в js ловлю.

Comment: Уже и битрикс появился, какие интересные подробности! Такие важные вещи надо сразу в вопросе указывать. Уверен, что для битрикса есть менее костыльное и правильное решение!

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что код вообще выполняется? По умолчанию, `script` теги, добавленные через `innerHTML` [выполняться не будут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations), так как это не безопасно.

Если же код выполняется, то происходит следующее. Переменная `cd` инициализируется, но нигде не используется. Поэтому логично, что вы не видите её в `window`.

Чтобы получить значение, либо измените код:

```js
window.cd = ...
```

Либо, если код не ваш, то можно добавить дополнительный блок `script` со следующим содержанием:

```js
window.cd = cd;
```

Как объяснил ниже Stepan Kasyanenko, переменная, инициализированая в одном блоке будет читаться и в последующих блоках.

Можете ещё анализировать само значение `res`. К примеру, если вы знаете, что структура кода не поменяется, то можно пропустить первые девять символов (`var cd =`), убрать последний (точка с запятой), и дальше использовать `JSON.parse` чтобы получить сам объект.

Учтите, что этот вариант очень хрупкий. Если код поменяется, то ваш перестанет работать. Поэтому лучше обратиться к тому, кто написал код, и попросить внести изменения, к примеру создав API который будет давать готовый результат в виде JSON ресурса.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду доставать сразу объект из res? Каким нибудь match ?

Comment: @Agapkin если вы сами формируете код, который генерирует ajax, то нет смысла делать дополнительную прослойку со `<script>`

Comment: @Agapkin, я изменил свой ответ в связи с вашим комментарием.

Comment: Вообще переменные объявленные в разных тегах script в глобальном контексте видны во всех тегах script.  Ничего `cd ` не локальная.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko: вы абсолютно правы! И благодаря вам, я, пробуя разное, нашел ещё одну вещь: оказывается, код внутри `script` вообще не должен выполняться. Спасибо вам.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko интересно то, что раньше код, вставленный в innerHTML, выполнялся. Это работало в ie6 на 100%. И я был уверен, что и сейчас он работает. Но оказывается, что нет. Спасибо ТС, благодаря ему мы узнали новое :)